# How to count rows in one column till treshold is reached in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am looking for a code that calculates after how many cycles a machine failed. After a treshold of 5 / > the machine has a failure. How can I write a code in python that counts the values in column 1 (from a csv file), till 5 / > is reached? Also I have data that starts above the threshold, so the code needs to count the values from values < 5. (In this case from datapoint 5 to 11 = 7 cycles). (I made up a small example here by myself)

68,15

25,22

15,9

5,55

2,68

3,25

3,75

4,28

4,78

4,95

5,01 <-----

5,22

5,78

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a Python script that can count the amount of consecutive values that are less than 5, in a list of values?

Assuming you can put the values into a list then:

```
values = [11.0, 10.2, 9.5, 8.8, 4.9, 4.3, 4.2, 9.9, 11.1]  # list of values

failure_count = 0  # variable that counts the failure values

for val in values:  # goes through the values
    if val < 5:  # checks for values less than 5
        failure_count += 1  # adds to the count

print(failure_count)

>> 3
```

If you want the count to reset after a set of failures has ended, then simply add in `failure_count = 0` in the code, accordingly.

A more pythonic way, if you don't care about sets of consecutive failures (and just want a count of all failures) is:

```
values = [11.0, 10.2, 9.5, 8.8, 4.9, 4.3, 4.2, 9.9, 11.1]  # list of values

failure_count = ["fail" for x in values if x < 5].count("fail")  # list comprehension

print(failure_count)

>> 3
```

Comment: Okay, and if I have 2 columns from a csv file and I need to go through the values of column 2, how can I do that?

Comment: Then just use `pandas.read_csv` from pandas to read the values from the column you want: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html